# Call update function from component without using task

Tags: components, parent-child, elm

I have an elm project with a the main app and a component.

I would like the component to have its own internal updates and also be able to update the main model.

I would like the component's `update` function to be able to run a `Cmd` which passes data to the main app and changes the main app url.

The only way I have found to be able to do this is by using `Task.perform` and `Task.succeed`.

Is it possible to do this without using `Task.perform` and `Task.succeed`?
What are the negatives of using the `Task.perform` and `Task.succeed` pattern in this scenario?

Comment: "We do not think in terms of reusable components." It's in BOLD, here: https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

In your parent model, store a copy of the child model. And in the parents update method, handle the child's message, and call the child's update function. IE:

```
--In Parent
type alias ParentModel = {
    childModel : ChildModel
}

Type Msg 
    = ChildMsg Child.Msg

case ParentMsg parentMsg ->
    let
        ( newChildModel, childMsg ) =
            Child.update parentMsg model.childModel
    in
        ( { model | childModel = newChildModel }, Cmd.map ParentMsg childMsg )

view model =
    Html.map ParentMsg (Child.view model.childModel)
    ...
```

Long answer:
Parent Child relationships are more of a Object Oriented style of programming, which is difficult to do in a functional language. Just as Functional Programming is hard to do in Object Oriented Languages. Much easier to use the language with how it was designed. If you are interested more into how to organize code in a functional style, check out [Richard Feldmans Scaling Elm video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoA4Txr4GUs) or if you are interested in organizing code across multiple pages in an elm app, check out this [example git repo Richard created](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example)